# WinForm ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, scrollviewer

I have an application in WPF that uses ScrollViewr and I want to port it to WinForms, is there an equivalent control for WinForms?

Reason:

WPF program is slow and I can't seem to learn how to render the program properly (GameOfLife).
Code:

```
    <ScrollViewer  Name="displayPlaceHolder" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Canvas Name="display" MouseMove="display_MouseMove" MouseDown="display_MouseDown" Cursor="Cross" KeyDown="global_KeyDown" Focusable="True" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: what's in your scrollviewer? could you show some code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try to use Panel with [AutoScroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx) property enabled.