# c# How to disable scroll for panel when active

Tags: c#, scrollbar, panel

I tried coding form with 3 controls: 
- panelMain includes one panel and one richtextbox.
set panelMain AutoScroll = true, when focused on richtextbox, and then deactive this form, then re-activate this form , phenomenon appears ,panelMain autoscrolls to top of richtextbox, but I don't want that . What I want is, when this form is re-activated, the current position of richtextbox will be fixed.

You can see the phenomenon at [video](https://youtu.be/nzQEA9VKzCM)

Design : [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have can using "ScrollViewer" In WPF, this is link document : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I using winform , not WPF

Comment: for winform http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570871/winform-scrollviewer

Comment: i using panel in winform, not scrollview in WPF.