Can I get a high resolution project on the screen even if the screen resolution is not large in C# Winform?
I am a beginner C# developer.
I am currently working on a company project using Winform.
The form size of the project is 3840*2160.
However, the display resolution of my computer monitor is 2560*1440.
In this case, how do I make sure that when I run the program, the screen doesn't get cut off and it's output to fit my monitor?
Thank you.

You can create complex layout which will support any resolution. In winforms it's using TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel. Another option is to create different form for different resolution/aspect ratio and show form which matches current resolution. This allows you to completely change UI, remove unnecessary UI elemens for smaller resolutions, hide something in menus, etc. Combining 2 those approaches leads to a responsive design.

Go for a layout that works with (at best) any resolution and is not bound to a specific one. You should be wary when someone told you their Monitor resolution. Its pretty common to have high resolution monitors with scaling applied. So if they use 200% scaling you are rather targeting Full HD and not 4K even if the Monitor has that resolution.

"how do I make sure that when I run the program, the screen doesn't get cut off and it's output to fit my monitor?" For that don't rely on the theory we might provide do an actual test on proper hardware.

When using WinForms, the magic words to get into dynamic layouts are Docking and Anchoring. With these you can anchor or dock a child control to a parent control, which automatically resizes the child when the parent size is changed (and the top level parent is your form).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570871/winform-scrollviewer

Are you filling the form with many small controls? If so, then anchoring and docking won't work.
